# How to get Column name in Classic Asp using RecordSet?

Tags: asp-classic

I am displaying data in a web report from table using Recordset.

This works fine upto 5000 records but fails while more then 5000 records.

**Recordset.Fields.Count gives Zero (0).**

Please let suggest me any alternative.

Thank you 
Sugam

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that the recordset is actually returning anything in the case of more than 5K records?

response.write Recordset.state

Here are the possible values for state.
0   Object is closed
1   Object is open
2   Object is connecting
4   Object is executing
8   Object is fetching

Also, make sure you don't have the page silently swallowing errors. My gut says there is an error in the query that returns 5K rows and that it has nothing to do with the rowcount. A good way to check this is to run the 5K query directly in the back-end DB and rule that out first.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I checked all possible ways. But still it is showing Zero count for Recordset.Fields.Count.
Query is fine, and report generates for 5K to 6K records but fails on huge data.

Thank you

Comment: Now My application is working with huge number of data. I just increased the timeout limit of Connection and Command and it works fine now.

Thank you,
Sugam